How do I set the drop-down menu UI of the list view?


standard : product  / custom : option__c
The drop-down menu Design of a list view created with a standard object is different from the Design of a drop-down menu created with a custom object.
I would like to express the Design of a list view created with a custom object like a standard Design .
There seems to be an issue in the list view of the new Design where Recently Viewed is not immediately updated when a specific record is read.
